# ModalPopupExtender OnShow Event

Tags: asp.net, events, modalpopupextender

When clicking a button, I have a ModalPopupExtender (Panel) that gets displayed. I can't seem to trigger any event during that process.

Adding an event to the button that opens the ModalPopupExtender doesnt work, as it never triggers. Adding the button as a trigger in my UpdatePanel also doesnt work.

Scenario: I have a gridview with a button outside of the gridview. Clicking the button opens up a ModalPopupExtender which needs to display the checkboxes clicked on the gridview. I have the code to get the checkboxes clicked on the Gridview, however I cant seem to use an event during the process of opening the ModalPopupExtender.

Comment: It is way too much code to post. It is simply an update panel (conditional parameter) with a gridview that has a checkbox column. And a button outside of the gridview that opens the ModalPopupExtender. On the ModalPopupExtender Panel that opens up, I want to use the check box values ticked on the gridview control. Just cant seem to trigger any event when the ModalPopupExtender is opened.